Why is relative change highly correlated but absolute values are not?
I have n "couples" (female-male pairs).
And I compute the correlation for trait A and B:
corr(trait_A_female, trait_A_male)
corr(trait_B_female, trait_B_male)

None of this gives a high correlation.
However corr(Δ_trait_A, Δ_trait_B) where
Δ_trait_A=trait_A_female-trait_A_male
Δ_trait_B=trait_B_female-trait_B_male

is actually quite high.
What could this imply? That even though the traits are not strongly correlated among partners, the relationship between A and B across couples is?
For a more biological interpretation (for anyone interested) trait_A is the observed phenotype and trait B is the genotype risk for such phenotype.

I edited your tags to better reflect your question.  I'm curious as to how you are doing correlations on phenotypes and genotypes.  Isn't phenotype a categorical variable? (I am not a biologist, so maybe I'm just mistaken here). I also wonder what the differences in your second box  actually mean.

phenotype is a continuous variable such as height, weight and so on. Δ_trait_A would mean Δ_polygenic_score_for_that_phenotype and Δ_trait_B would be Δ_actual_phenotype. Someone told me that I'm just re-capturing the correlation between PGS (polygenic score) and phenotype, meaning corr(PGS, phenotype) without the Δ.

Then I would check your data and code, at least if by  "pairs" you mean romantic pairs of humans. Height and weight are strongly correlated in human couples.

For sure. Yes, that's what I meant by pairs. And yes height and weight are highly correlated. What I was trying to see was if the difference in actual phenotype and the difference in genetic risk was associated. corr(Δphenotype, Δrisk) across couples. But then someone told me corr(Δphenotype, Δrisk) is high because corr(phenotype, risk) for all individuals is high, which kind of makes sense.

It may be easier to explain if you added plots to illustrate the relationships.

In your comment you say height and weight are correlated. But in your question you say they are not.

I have several other phenotypes that aren't. I'm looking at around 40 phenotypes.
